# how to use the user-defind-axis in matrix job

Tags: jenkins

I have a matrix job that need to run bash script on the axis.

on each axis I have a bash script that run some commands

how can use those variables ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the axis like this

**echo ${axis-name}**

let me know if it works for you